# "The Azure PowerShell session has not been properly initialized" error message in Octopus

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell, octopus-deploy, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to run the `Get-AzureRmEventHubNamespaceKey` cmdlet in an Azure Powershell step within Octopus.

I am getting the following error:

```
Get-AzureRmEventHubNamespaceKey : The Azure PowerShell session has not been properly 
                                  initialized.  Please import the module and try again
```

The module is installed in the following directory on the Octopus server:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft 
     SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.EventHub`

I have tried importing the module first as part of the same step:

`Import-Module –Name "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\AzureRM.EventHub" -Verbose`

And I can see in the output that it has been imported:

`VERBOSE: Importing cmdlet 'Get-AzureRmEventHubNamespaceKey'.`

But it is immediately followed by the above error. If I RDP to the octopus server and run directly from there it runs fine.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: i wonder if you have to login first? try updating the module also?

Comment: This could be because of path mismatch when remote. Can you try uninstall all previous AzurePowershell Modules and try getting the latest. Note: Get-AzureRmEventHubNamespaceKey is retired from 5.0.0 and replaced with Get-AzureRmEventHubKey

Answer (score 0):

To use any Azure related commands from your machine, you need to [log in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azurerm/authenticate-azureps?view=azurermps-4.4.1) first.

Note that there are several Azure modules, and each has a different login cmdlet, but the link above is specific to the module you're using.